# looking for string split and update each property

Tags: c#

I have a class "DataCls" and from some other source I get "Message" string with "propertyName:value" format.

```
public class DataCls
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}

dataCls.Message = "[AE][1W] Message:Console Station is not available Priority:Info Time:Sep 21 2016  1:13PM Tag:/System Components/R431ESV/Stations/Console Stations/CStn01";
```

1. Message: sample message
2. Priority: Info
3. Time: Sep 21 2016  1:13PM
4. Tag: /abc/pqr/xyz

Now I need to split this string and update each property of class "DataCls" with above value. Please suggest!!!

I tried with with below, but didn't work,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataCls dataCls = new DataCls();

        dataCls.Message = "[AE][1W] Message:sample message Priority:Info Time:Sep 21 2016  1:13PM Tag:/abc/pqr/xyz";

        dataCls.Message = dataCls.Message.Split(':')[1].ToString();
        dataCls.Priority = dataCls.Message.Split(':')[2].ToString();//error
    }
```

Comment: Split('{char}') produces an array of strings with the delimiter of the char you input. There is no need to call ToString(), and the array returned is 0 indexed.

Comment: there are 2 issue with my code. 1. Message is at index 1, once that is derived, then further I can't derived anything as Message is changed 2. Time also have colon(:) in time.

Comment: I wouldn't use ':' as your seperator as you are using it in your date format aswell..

Comment: @Danoram, Is there anything I can do with Regex, please suggest!1

Comment: do you have control over the input string?  I would suggest changing the char to split on to one that is less likely to occur, say the pipe `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fixed words in the message to get the parts between it:

```
static void Main()
{
    DataCls ci = new DataCls();
    ci.Parse( "[AE][1W] Message:Console Station is not available Priority:Info Time:Sep 21 2016  1:13PM Tag:/System Components/R431ESV/Stations/Console Stations/CStn01" );
}

public class DataCls
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public void Parse( string parseStr )
    {
        const string MESSAGE_MARKER = "Message:";
        const string PRIORITY_MARKER = "Priority:";
        const string TIME_MARKER = "Time:";
        const string TAG_MARKER = "Tag:";

        this.Message = GetTextPart( parseStr, MESSAGE_MARKER, PRIORITY_MARKER );
        this.Priority = GetTextPart( parseStr, PRIORITY_MARKER, TIME_MARKER );
        this.Time = DateTime.Parse( GetTextPart( parseStr, TIME_MARKER, TAG_MARKER ) );
        this.Tag = GetTextPart( parseStr, TAG_MARKER, null );
    }

    private string GetTextPart( string text, string before, string after )
    {
        string result = null;

        int posBefore = text.IndexOf( before );

        if( after != null )
        {
            int posAfter = text.IndexOf( after );
            result = text.Remove( posAfter ).Substring( posBefore + before.Length ).TrimEnd();
        }
        else
            result = text.Substring( posBefore + before.Length );

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in your DataCls

```
public class DataCls
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public void ProcessMessage(string message)
    {
        var indexMessage = message.IndexOf("Message");
        var indexPriority = message.IndexOf("Priority");
        var indexTime = message.IndexOf("Time");
        var indexTag = message.IndexOf("Tag");

        this.Message = message.Substring(indexMessage + 8, indexPriority - indexMessage - 9);
        this.Priority = message.Substring(indexPriority + 9, indexTime - indexPriority - 10);
        var time = message.Substring(indexTime + 5, indexTag - indexTime - 6);
        this.Time = DateTime.Parse(time);
        this.Tag = message.Substring(indexTag + 4, message.Length - indexTag-4);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting error at line ... this.Message = message.Substring(indexMessage + 8, indexPriority - indexMessage - 9);

Comment: I tested this with the given example. I assume that indexMessage or indexProperty is -1 in the tested by you case which means that some of "propertyName:value" is/are missing.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple trick

```
using System;
namespace program
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataCls dataCls = new DataCls();

            string message = "[AE][1W] Message:sample message Priority:Info Time:Sep 21 2016  1:13PM Tag:/abc/pqr/xyz";
            message = message.Replace("Message:","::").Replace("Priority:","::").Replace("Time:","::").Replace("Tag:","::");
            var parts = message.Split("::");
            dataCls.Message = parts[0];
            dataCls.Priority = parts[1];
            dataCls.Time  = Convert.ToDateTime(parts[2]);
            dataCls.Tag = parts[3];
        }
    }

    public class DataCls
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Priority { get; set; }
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a round-about way of doing it, but it worked for me:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataCls dataCls = new DataCls();

        string Message = "[AE][1W] Message:sample message Priority:Info Time:Sep 21 2016  1:13PM Tag:/abc/pqr/xyz";

        dataCls.Message = Message.Substring(Message.IndexOf("Message:")+8);
        dataCls.Message = dataCls.Message.Substring(0, dataCls.Message.LastIndexOf("Priority"));

        dataCls.Priority = Message.Substring(Message.IndexOf("Priority:")+9);
        dataCls.Priority = dataCls.Priority.Substring(0,dataCls.Priority.LastIndexOf("Time"));

        string Time = Message.Substring(Message.IndexOf("Time"));
        Time = Time.Substring(0, Time.LastIndexOf("Tag"));
        dataCls.Time = Convert.ToDateTime(Time.Substring(Time.IndexOf(":")+1));

        dataCls.Tag = Message.Substring(Message.IndexOf("Tag:")+4);
        dataCls.Tag = dataCls.Tag.Substring(0);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can temporarily change the colons in your time to pipes, split, then replace

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataCls dataCls = new DataCls();

    dataCls.Message = "[AE][1W] Message:sample message Priority:Info Time:Sep 21 2016  1:13PM Tag:/abc/pqr/xyz";
    dataCls.Message = dataCls.Message.Replace("me:",me|");
    int index = dataCls.Message.IndexOf("Tag")-6;
    dataCls.Message.SubString(index,1)="|";
    string[] parts = dataCls.Message.Split(';');
    dataCls.Message = parts[1];
    dataCls.Priority = parts[3].Replace("|",":");
    dataCls.Tag = parts[5];
}
```

Comment: how to get Time as this contains colon(:) in time

Comment: is there anything I can use Regex?

Comment: Edited to fix the time issue

Comment: Oh - I see the second colon. Hold on

Comment: what is: dataCls.Message.Replace("me:", me | ");

Comment: Edited - substring was missing .Message. Try again